# Keep Traffic Separate but Allow communication

Tags: networking, router

I have 10 computers on Network A and 10 IP phones on Network B.  Network A and B are physically separate with separate routers 100 MB/s.  The reason they are on two different networks is because call quality on the IP phones was dropping when the computers chew up bandwidth on the LAN for various reasons.

I want to connect Network A and Network B, but I want the traffic for the computers/phones to still be routed through their separate Routers.  I am concerned that if I turn off the DHCP server on Router B and then connect that to Router A, then Router A will take the entire load from the phones and the computers again.

So my question is, **does disabling DHCP on Router B and connecting it to Router A cause Router A to take on the entire network load?** If so, is there any way to connect LANs between Router A and Router B while keeping most traffic separate to each router?

Comment: If I am understanding your request, you need a 3rd router, to route between the two networks. then add a static route between them with a high metric value, so each lan can communicate with the other but only if they specifically want to access an address on the other network. that would leave each network with their own default gateway, which they will use to access the internet, and the high metric on the link between them will keep them from selecting the wrong gateway, or unnecessarily using the other networks resources. you don;t explain what 'communication' you want. can you expound?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want.  Do you have any resources or tutorials handy for doing that?

Comment: too much of it depends on your hardware and the software interfaces it provides. once you decide on a router, look into how to create a static route with it. the trick is to make the metric high, so that hosts will never select the route between the networks unless they have to.

Comment: @FrankThomas, why do you need a 3rd router?  You should just need a cable between router 1 and router 2 and have static routes setup in each one to communicate with the other.

Comment: Depends on the grade of router. most cheaper commercially available routers have only two interfaces, the inside (usually multiport, but still one interface) and the outside, both of which are in use. if the routers have 3 "sides" then yes, what you suggest would work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, disabling DHCP on router B and connecting it to router A will cause A to take on the entire load.

If these routers are just routers and not doing NAT, then in order to connect them you just need to connect the WAN sides of both routers together using a switch and then add static routes from one router to the other.  However, I'm guessing your router are probably doing NAT, so that won't work either.

Your best bet is probably going to be connecting the two routers on the LAN side of each one, and then forcing one of the networks to be statically assigned (no DHCP).  You'll still need to setup static routes in each one as well to route traffic between the two networks.

Comment: That makes sense and seems like a simple enough solution.  So to be clear... Router A could be 192.168.1.1 with DHCP assigning 192.168.1.x and then Router B could be 192.168.2.1 and all devices that are supposed to stay on router B would be statically assigned 192.168.2.x

Comment: Right, you'd have to configure clients on network B manually with `192.168.2.X` addresses with the Default Gateway set to `192.168.2.1`.